# Opening two filenames

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to build a function that asks the user to type in a source filename and a destination filename; opens the files, loops through the contents of the source file line-by-line, writing each one to the destination file; and then closes both files. Make sure that all work with the files happens inside of a try block. If an IOError occurs, the script should print a message saying that there was an error working with one of the files and ask the user to enter in the filenames again. Here is what I have so far:

```
while True:
try:
    file = open(filename)
    line = file.readline()
    while line != "":
        print(line)
        line = file.readline()
    file.close()
    break
except IOError:
    print("There was a problem accessing file '" + filename + "'." + \
          "Please enter a different filename.")
    filename = input("> ")
```

However, I don't know how to ask the user for 1.) user input 2.) ask for both the filename and destination filename 3.) writing each source to the destination file.  Help if you can..

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that I could show you.

To do input

```
inputFileName = str(raw_input("Enter the input file: "))
outputFileName = str(raw_input("Enter the output file name: "))
```

Also, to learn about using files you can check out a good tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm).
Finally, you shouldn't be running your file = open(filename) in a while loop. Only the reading of the lines should be done in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add a little to your existing code:

```
in_filename = input('input from filename: ')
ou_filename = input('output to filename: ')
while True:
  try:
    infile = open(in_filename)
    oufile = open(ou_filename, 'w')
    line = infile.readline()
    while line != "":
        # print(line)
        oufile.write(line)
        line = infile.readline()
    infile.close()
    oufile.close()
    break
  except IOError:
    print("There was a problem accessing file '" + in_filename + "'." + \
          "or maybe '" + ou_filename + "'." + \
          "Please enter different filenames.")
    in_filename = input('input from filename: ')
    ou_filename = input('output to filename: ')
```

Of course, there are **many** things left to improve here -- for example, by insisting that everything be within a single try/except statement, you don't know, in the error message, which of the two files gave problems.

But at least I've added the `in_` and `ou_` prefixes to distinguish input from output, and avoided using the built-in name `file` as a variable name (trampling over built-in names is a notorious trap for beginners, which gives no problems... until it suddenly does:-).

Answer (score 0):

1.2)  You can get the user input and both filename by sys.argv [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html).
3) File operation.  [file](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)